# sort array before using mergeObjects MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am doing a query in mongo db where I group some documents and I need to merge objects, but the objects has a key of date and I would like to sort the documents before merge objects to have the last values of the objects by date.

Is it possible??

Comment: Start here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/, or if you are using the aggregation framework, here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already could, I had to use two groups in the aggregation, the first one sorted the array of documents that I wanted to merge and then the second group merged the objects.